# about android Bundle error (from fragment to activity)

Tags: android, android-intent, fragment, bundle

I wanna pass the data from fragmentdialog to MainActivity

It is the code for sending calendar data in fragment

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity() , MainActivity.class);
 timePick.getCurrentMinute());
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 bundle.putLong("mili", mCalendar.getTimeInMillis());
 intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

this is the code for receiving date in MainActivity

```
long a = getIntent().getExtras().getLong("mili");
```

This part make some errors.

plz help me

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: You should consider communicating between your fragment and your activity using an interface then just call that interface's method and pass whatever you want

Comment: Thank you for your help. getIntent().getExtras().getLong("mili"); is Nullpoint error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send data from Fragment to Activity, the recommended way of doing it is as shown in the answer to the question here [Robust way to pass value back from Dialog to Activity on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13435118/robust-way-to-pass-value-back-from-dialog-to-activity-on-android). This is the preferred way of passing your values.

What you have to do is create an interface in your fragment and make your activity implement this interface listener. Then pass your results. This method is recommended by the Android development team.

Another way of doing this would be to call getActivity() from your fragment which would pass it an instance of the Activity that created this fragment from where you can call any method on the parent activity (by first casting the result to type of parent activity).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve easily but implementing the interface between activity and fragment.Like this
first create **interface**

```
public interface CallBackListener {
    public void onCallBack(Long mili);
}
```

Then **implement this interface to the Activity** you want to get data and supposing its the parent activity of fragment like this

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements CallBackListener {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onCallBack(Long mili){
        //take value of mili as you wanted.
    }
}
```

And in your fragmentdialog just call the method like given below when you want callback or data.

```
CallBackListener callBackListener = (CallBackListener) getActivity();
callBackListener.onCallBack(mili);
```