# Android: Call onClick from fragment/activity for views within Custom Dialog

Tags: android, android-fragments, customdialog

I've created a custom dialog, which has multiple views within it.
On click of these Views, I would like to start activities for results, like Camera, Gallery, etc.

CustomDialog

```
public class CustomDialog extends BottomBaseDialog {
    public static LinearLayout ll_camera;
    public static LinearLayout ll_gallery;

    public CustomDialog(Context context, View animateView) {
        super(context, animateView);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView() {
        View inflate = View.inflate(context, R.layout.dialog_custom, null);

        ll_camera = ViewFindUtils.find(inflate, R.id.camera_linear_layout);
        ll_gallery = ViewFindUtils.find(inflate, R.id.gallery_linear_layout);

        return inflate;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean setUiBeforShow() {
        ll_camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // OPEN INTENT FOR CAMERA
                dismiss();
            }
        });
        ll_gallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // OPEN INTENT FOR GALLERY
                dismiss();
            }
        });

        return false;
    }
}
```

Then within my fragment, I've displayed this dialog by

```
IOSTaoBaoDialog dialog = new IOSTaoBaoDialog(getActivity(), AddActivity.drawerLayout);
dialog.show();
```

How can I call onClick for the Camera and Gallery Linear Layout views from within my Fragment?
I also need to get the result of the activities back into the fragment, so I can process it.
Please suggest.

I've done a lot of search and I came across suggestions to use Interfaces, however, I do not clearly understand how that will work.

Comment: What do you mean you want to call onClick?

Comment: I want to attach onClick listeners to the views for Gallery and Camera. When these views are clicked (within the dialog), i want to start intents for the default gallery or camera app. And I want the result from those intents to be returned to my calling fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution for this, for if somebody else also gets stuck in the same situation:

I passed the instance of my calling fragment to the dialog. Then from within the dialog, I called the fragment.startActivityForResult() method. So when the result was received, it was sent to the onActivityResult() method of the fragment.

The code is:

Dialog:

```
public class SelectApplicationDialog extends BottomBaseDialog {
    public static LinearLayout ll_camera;
    public static LinearLayout ll_gallery;

    Fragment fragment;

    public SelectApplicationDialog(Context context, View animateView, Fragment fragment) {
        super(context, animateView);
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView() {
        View inflate = View.inflate(context, R.layout.dialog_select_application, null);

        ll_camera = ViewFindUtils.find(inflate, R.id.camera_linear_layout);

        ll_gallery = ViewFindUtils.find(inflate, R.id.gallery_linear_layout);

        return inflate;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean setUiBeforShow() {
        ll_camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                File externalStorageFile = new File(imagePath);

                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                AddCourseFragment.imageUri = Uri.fromFile(externalStorageFile);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, AddCourseFragment.imageUri);
                fragment.startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                dismiss();
            }
        });
        ll_gallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                fragment.startActivityForResult(pickPhoto, 2);
                dismiss();
            }
        });

        return false;
    }
}
```

Calling Fragment:

```
public void openUploadImageDialog() {
    SelectApplicationDialog dialog = new SelectApplicationDialog(getContext(), 
            AddActivity.addLinearLayout, AddCourseFragment.this);
    dialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
IOSTaoBaoDialog dialog = new IOSTaoBaoDialog(getActivity(), AddActivity.drawerLayout);
dialog.show();
```

### Change To

```
IOSTaoBaoDialog dialog = new IOSTaoBaoDialog(getparent(), AddActivity.drawerLayout);
dialog.show();
```

### If This Not Work Then Try

```
IOSTaoBaoDialog dialog = new IOSTaoBaoDialog(getActivity().getparent(), AddActivity.drawerLayout);
dialog.show();
```

### OR

```
IOSTaoBaoDialog dialog = new IOSTaoBaoDialog(getparent().getActivity(), AddActivity.drawerLayout);
    dialog.show();
```

### For startActivityForResult()

```
IF(getparent() == null) 
{
 startActivityForResult();
}else
{
 getparent().startActivityForResult();
}
```

Comment: How will this make any difference?

Comment: I did, but how do I call startActivityForResult from my Dialog?

Comment: Ok For startActivityForResult First check where result Going                             IF(getparent() == null)   { message }else{ message}   try if if getparent() is not null just change getparent().startActivityForResult();

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `DialogFragment`, [look at this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977392/android-dialogfragment-vs-dialog/21032871#21032871)  Here are the two important lines from that answer:

In calling Fragment:

`dialog.setTargetFragment(this, YES_NO_CALL);`

In DialogFragment:

`getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), Activity.RESULT_OK, null);`

Basically, when you call the `DialogFragment`, you need to call `setTargetFragment` with a request code.  Then in your fragment, you handle the response in `onActivityResult`.

Comment: I cannot call DialogFragment, because the BottomBaseDialog is a library that I'm using.

Comment: Well I'm not sure what that library is, can you call `getTargetFragment()` from it?

Comment: No, the base class extends Dialog, and not DialogFragment

Comment: Well then I believe you are forced to implement your own interface.  It's quite simple, [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13435204/1199931)

Comment: Yes, I thought of doing this first. But see, I don't want to return something from the Dialog to the Fragment. On the contrary, I want to call a method of my fragment from within the Dialog. How can I do that with interfaces?

Comment: I'm unable to cast the interface to the Activity.